# in heroku nodemon app crash when i am trying to run the server.heroku logs --tail this error showing node/internalmodule/cjsloader936

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

GITHUB LINK - https://github.com/sc43412/ecomerce-api.git

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTKu8.png) demon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
2022-03-11T18:52:20.928289+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch.Stopping process with SIGKILLError: Cannot find module '../models/Product'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. And please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/354577)